# Ffmpeg with few audio inputs as tracks and separate offset for each

Tags: ffmpeg

I have one video file (without audio) and 2 language files. I need to mix both audio files as language tracks, but each audio file can start at different offset. So far I am unlucky to do so. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it myself. English starts at second 5, italian starts at second 9.

```
ffmpeg -i video_without_sound.mp4 -i en.mp3 -i it.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a -c:v copy -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=5000|5000;[2:a]adelay=9000|9000"  -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 language=ita -shortest  output.mp4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).